# MVC3 WebGrid header alignment

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, webgrid

WebGrid (Razor)

How can the headers alignment be set?

I need to be able to change the alignment for each column (could be different)

It seems to be a all or nothing deal nor does it seem to take the alignment of the child TD.

Comment: Each `td` or `th` has to have its `text-alignment` set individually.

Answer (score 1):

There currently is not a way to set a different style for each column header using the WebGrid in MVC 3.  You can however use the tableStyle property to set the style for all column headers.

.header {
        text-align: left;
    }

@var grid = new WebGrid(Model);

@grid.GetHtml(headerStyle: "header")